# Laravel Getting Error in exception handler:bootstrap/compiled.php:768 when App::abort(404);

Tags: laravel, error-handling

I use:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
   return App::make('ErrorController')->get404Error($exception);
});
```

in \app\filters.php to handle errors 404, it works ok for all the pages like:

"http://example.com/page1, http://example.com/page2, etc.."

But when I use 2 level URL like:

"http://example.com/news/page1"

404 dosen't work if there is a missing page/slug, and an "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." comes, so I trigger 404 error by adding "App::abort(404);" in a controller before the error comes because of the non exisiting slug, then It gives me "Error in exception handler: .../bootstrap/compiled.php:768" . doesn't matter if I have debug true or false.

How can I trigger a 404 error without getting error handler error?, is that possible?

Many thanks.